# How to Fix Non-serializable objects should not be stored in "HttpSession" objects (squid:S2441)

Tags: java, sonarqube, serializable, httpsession

I'm getting the Sonarqube defect

```
Non-serializable objects should not be stored in "HttpSession" objects (squid:S2441)
```

for the saving in `Httpsession`, code:

```
public static HttpSession setSessionAttribute(final HttpSession session, 
final String attributeName,
        final Object attributeValue) {
    session.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
    return session;
  }
```

Comment: `implements Serializable`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is there any problem with making it serializable? Are you asking how to do it?

Comment: Hi Pshemo, i am passing different objects to save it in session. Is i have to to implement serializable for all objects

Comment: what's your sonarqube version?

Comment: sonar lint 3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your objects that you are adding as attribute to HttpSession has to be Serializable (so that the session with be Serializable),

SonarQube search for every setAttribute on HttpSession that object is primitive or implements Serializable, [Code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/serialization/SerializableObjectInSessionCheck.java#L45):

```
if (!type.isPrimitive() && !type.isSubtypeOf("java.io.Serializable")) { 
      addIssue(argument, "Make \"" + type + "\" serializable or don't store it in the session."); 
    }
```

There's also an [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1810) reported and should be fixed in version 
4.2 with handling arrays.

If you can fix your code, change attributeValue to Serializable

```
public static HttpSession setSessionAttribute(final HttpSession session, 
final String attributeName,
        final Serializable attributeValue) {
    session.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
    return session;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Non-serializable objects should not be stored in "HttpSession" objects (squid:[S2441](https://sbforge.org/sonar/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2441))

Compliant Solution: In order for session replication to work, the values the application stores as attributes in the session must implement the Serializable interface.

```java
public class Address implements Serializable {
  //...
}

//...
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("address", new Address());  // Compliant; Address is serializable
```

> [CWE-579](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/579.html): J2EE Bad Practices: Non-serializable Object Stored in Session leads to replication problem across multiple JVMs

A J2EE application can make use of multiple JVMs in order to improve application reliability and performance. In order to make the multiple JVMs appear as a single application to the end user, the **J2EE container can replicate an HttpSession object across multiple JVMs** so that if one JVM becomes unavailable another can step in and take its place without disrupting the flow of the application. This is only possible if all session data is serializable, allowing the session to be duplicated between the JVMs.

Example of Cluster ReplicationTransmitter<sup>[tomcat-5.5](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html), [hazelcast.org](https://hazelcast.org/use-cases/web-session-clustering-tomcat-replication/)</sup>.

[image]

---

Form [Sonar-Java](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava.html) source of [`SerializableObjectInSessionCheck`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/serialization/SerializableObjectInSessionCheck.java#L45)

```java
@Rule(key = "S2441")
public class SerializableObjectInSessionCheck extends AbstractMethodDetection {

  @Override
  protected void onMethodInvocationFound(MethodInvocationTree mit) {
    ExpressionTree argument = mit.arguments().get(1);
    Type type = argument.symbolType();
    if (!isSerializable(type)) {
      String andParameters = isParametrized(type) ? " and its parameters" : "";
      reportIssue(argument, "Make \"" + type + "\"" + andParameters + " serializable or don't store it in the session.");
    }
  }
}
```